# Java spring rest service does not cast parameter

Tags: java, spring

I'm create REST api with springFramework. Create products from post api, but rest method does not cast the parameters with TitleCase parameter name.

My Product model:

```
public class Product extends BaseModel {

    private String title;
    private String shortDescription;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getShortDescription() {
        return shortDescription;
    }

    public void setShortDescription(String shortDescription) {
        this.shortDescription = shortDescription;
    }
}
```

My Product REST Api:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/product", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public ApiResponse Insert(@RequestBody Product model){
    ApiResponse response = new ApiResponse();

    try{
        response.setData(_service.Insert(model));
        response.setSuccess(true);
    } catch (Exception ex){
        response = _service.HandleException(ex);
    }

    return response;
}
```

Worked Request Object:

```
{
    "title" : "TEST",
    "shortDescription" : "SD",
    "longDescription" : "LD"
}
```

Not Worked Request Object:

```
{
    "Title" : "TEST",
    "ShortDescription" : "SD",
    "LongDescription" : "LD"
}
```

I want both options to work. I'm new to Java, so I did not know how to get around to it, so I wanted to ask.

UPDATED

Jackson Config File

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class JacksonConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);

        return mapper;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: configure your json deserialiser  to ignore the properties case (e.g. for jackson: objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);

Comment: Where should I make this configuration? public static void main(String[] args) or rest api controller.

Comment: @EmanueleIvaldi added to java config file but not working

Comment: I added a small test to show jackson working fine with that configuration..the problem must be something else, double check the error you are getting, maybe it's a different one now, see darshan response too, you may need to configure   mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
package com.example;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;


import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

public class Test {

private ObjectMapper mapper;

public static class A{

    private int test;

    public int getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(int test) {
        this.test = test;
    }
}

@Before
public void setUp(){
    mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
}

@Test
public void deserialise() throws Exception {
    String json = "{\"test\":\"2\"}";
    assertThat(mapper.readValue(json, A.class).getTest(), is(2));
}

@Test
public void deserialiseIgnoringCase() throws Exception {
    String json = "{\"Test\":\"2\"}";
    assertThat(mapper.readValue(json, A.class).getTest(), is(2));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`Product` model does not seem to have `longDescription` field. That might be the reason why deserialisation will fail (as there is no `@JsonIgnore`) on `Product` class. Below snippet works fine:

```
class Product {
    private String title;
    private String shortDescription;
    private String longDescription;
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getShortDescription() {
        return shortDescription;
    }
    public void setShortDescription(String shortDescription) {
        this.shortDescription = shortDescription;
    }
    public String getLongDescription() {
        return longDescription;
    }
    public void setLongDescription(String longDescription) {
        this.longDescription = longDescription;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
     ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
     mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
     Product product = mapper.readValue("{\"Title\" : \"TEST\",\"ShortDescription\" : \"SD\",\"LongDescription\" : \"LD\"}", Product.class);
     System.out.println(product.getShortDescription());
}
```

It will throw an `Exception` if you comment out `longDescription`.